# Remove dom element without knowing its parent?

Tags: javascript, removechild

Is it possible to remove a dom element that has no parent other than the body tag? I know this would be easy with a framework like jquery, but I'm trying to stick to straight javascript.

Here's the code I've found to do it otherwise:

```
function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv){
     if (childDiv == parentDiv) {
          alert("The parent div cannot be removed.");
     }
     else if (document.getElementById(childDiv)) {     
          var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
          var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
          parent.removeChild(child);
     }
     else {
          alert("Child div has already been removed or does not exist.");
          return false;
     }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI `body` is a perfectly valid parent.

Comment: Every single element has a parent element

Comment: @connorspiracist except `document`

Comment: @adam `document` isn't an element, it's a node (document node) and therefore not classed as a element

Comment: Document fragments which aren't added to the tree don't have parents.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You should be able to get the parent of the element, then remove the element from that

```
function removeElement(el) {
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

**Update**

You can set this as a new method on the HTMLElement:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.remove = function() { this.parentNode.removeChild(this); return this; }
```

And then do `el.remove()` (which will also return the element)

Comment: Updating to the correct answer because it is more modular / inclusive of different scenarios. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

```
childDiv.remove();
```

works in Chrome 25.0.1364.155

Note that this does not work in IE11 or Opera Mini but is supported by all other browsers.

See here: [reference to childnode-remove on caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=childnode-remove)

Comment: As documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove - including a polyfill

Comment: Just tested it. `$("#answer-15480206").remove()` but then I had to refresh the page to upvote you.

Answer (score 16):

I think you can do something like...

```
var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
//var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

See [node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode) for more info on that.

Answer (score 6):

```
document.body.removeChild(child);
```

Comment: @unknown: this answer only works for nodes that are immediate descendants of `document.body`. The other answers work for all cases, including descendants of `document.body`.

Comment: As above, this answer only works on elements that are immediate descendants of body. Can someone moderate this?

Comment: read the question: «a dom element that has no parent other than the body tag», so my response is perfectly valable

Answer (score 4):

Removing element using `outerHTML` property

```
remElement(document.getElementById('title'));
remElement(document.getElementById('alpha'));

function remElement(obj) {
obj.outerHTML="";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function to simply remove an element using id:

```
function removeElement (id) { 
  document.getElementById(id).parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById(id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, you basically don't need to know the parent to delete a DOM element from DOM, look at the below code, see how is the order to delete a node element in JavaScript:

`Element` + `parentNode` + `removeChild(Element);`

As you see we find the element first, then using .parentNode and then remove the child which is the Element again, so we don't need to know the parent at all!

So now look the real code:

```
var navigation = document.getElementById('navigation');
if(navigation) {
  navigation.parentNode.removeChild(navigation);
}
```

or as a function

```
function removeNode(element) {
  if(element) { //check if it's not null
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  } 
} //call it like : removeNode(document.getElementById('navigation'));
```

Also jQuery has remove() function which is widely use, like:

```
$('#navigation').remove();
```

Also there is native `ChildNode.remove()` which is not in IE and old browsers, but you can polyfill it, look the suggested polyfill from MDN:

> **Polyfill**
>
>   You can polyfill the remove() method in Internet Explorer 9 and higher
>   with the following code:

```
//from:https://github.com/jserz/js_piece/blob/master/DOM/ChildNode/remove()/remove().md
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('remove')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'remove', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function remove() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, CharacterData.prototype, DocumentType.prototype]);
```

If you like to learn more about it, visit this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) on MDN.